# Multivalued attributes in Relational databases?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

How well an idea are multi-valued attributes in a relational database when they are to be referred extensively?

Let me give you an example to show what I mean. Suppose I have the following table:

```
UserID          Attribute1

User1           a,b,c
User2           x,y,z
User3           a,x,y
User4           c,b,z
[a,b,c,x,y,z are to be strings]
```

There is another user `User5` to whom I have to make some suggestions about other users based on whether his `Attribute1` matches any one of other 4 users or not.

*[In graph databases, the task could have been much easier as I could have created multiple nodes from the respective users using the same relationship.]*

Now, this table is just a micro-level abstraction of what an actual database will look like. The number of rows in a table may run into hundreds of thousands, if not millions. Also, the multiple values may actually be a lot more than 3. Apart from this, the database can be under heavy load, and in that situation, there may be some issues.

So, are multi-valued attributes helpful in such cases? Or is there any better way of doing the same? One obvious way I can think of is to store it as:

```
UserID          Attribute1

User1           a
User1           b
User1           c
User2           x
User2           y
User2           z
User3           a
User3           x
User3           y
User4           c
User4           b
User4           z
```

Any faster way of dealing such situations in databases? Or are there any built-in features of modern-day databases to exploit?

Comment: My intuition says that the relational part of a relational database is much more heavily optimized than the string-matching part :-)  Databases almost always work best and are most easily optimized when in their most normalized form, which would be the latter option (all attributes spread out into multiple rows).

Comment: Reporting databases usually perform better with a well thought denormalization..

Comment: http://www.builderau.com.au/architect/database/soa/Designing-databases-for-reporting-brings-clients-higher-ROI/0,339024547,320275759,00.htm

Comment: @mellamokb: "Databases almost always work best and are most easily optimized when in their most normalized form" -- not true: the highest normal form is [6NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form) may result in an 'explosion' of tables, requiring many joins to write the simplest of queries and forcing one to use triggers or other procedural code to enforce inter-table constraints, neither of which is good for optimization. Also a note that if a 5NF design exhibits no redundancy there may be little practical reason to take it to 6NF just to eliminate certain non-trivial dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having multiple values in a field is only useful if the data is dead weight in the database, i.e. if you only read the field out of the database and process it afterwards.

As soon as you want to use the values in the field in a query, you will take a huge performance hit from having to parse the value to compare it. If you put the values in separate records as in your second example, so that you can add an index on it, it's not unrealistic that the query will be 10 000 times faster.

Having a million records in a table is not a problem. We have some tables that have over 100 million records in them.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from what the others have said regarding normalization, I'd like to answer to the "*Or any inbuilt feature of modern-day databses to exploit?*" part of your question:

PostgreSQL has a pretty nifty extension called `hstore` which does exactly that and in a highly optimized manner.

The `hstore` data type is essentially a key/value pair, where you can store anything. In your example something like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_attributes
(user_id, , attributes)
VALUES
(1, ('att1 => x, att2 => y'));
```

Will insert the keys `att1` and `att2` into the column attributes. This can be indexed to make lookups fast.

You can query the data using this syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_attributes
WHERE attributes @> ('att1 => "Some Value"')
```

This will return all rows that have a key named `att1` and where that is mapped to the value "Some Value". The above statement will use an existing index on the column, so the lookup is nearly as fast as with a "real" column. The above statement takes ~2ms on my laptop to find a row in a table with 100.000 rows.

You can also query for rows that have a specific attribute defined regardless of the value:

```
SELECT user_id,
       (attributes -> 'att1')
FROM user_attributes
WHERE attributes ? 'att1'
```

will find all rows where `att1` is defined and will output the value for those.

Answer (score 1):

For a n-n table you could normalize it to 3 tables (in a transactional model) users - user_attribute - attributes where the user_attribute table consists out of the primary key of users and attributes.. Keys are usually indexed and therefore quite fast for read ops

EDIT AFTER QUESTION

```
Users
int Id PrimaryKey
string name
```

---

```
User_Attribute
UserId PrimaryKey (FK to Users.Id)
AttributeId PrimaryKey (FK to Attributes.Id)
```

---

```
Attributes
int Id PrimaryKey
Value
```

this would result in a table holding only the users, a table holding only the attributes and a table holding which user is holding what

for instance

```
   Users      User_Attribute      Attrubutes      
id  Name   UserId AttributeId  Id Value
1   User1  1      1            1  Att1
2   User2  1      2            2  Att2
           2      1            3  Att3  
           2      3
```

Comment: I couldn't get what you meant to say... Can you be please more clear? I mean can you explain with reference to the above example a bit?

Comment: Okay... Denormalization is the way to go in such cases then?